# Need to convert OMF file to ELF file format

Tags: elf, keil, firmware, 8051, omf

I'm using a `Keil C51` tool to compile my firmware which outputs a `.obj` file (I'm writing firmware for an 8051). However, I'm looking towards using another tool to debug the firmware which only takes in elf or dwarf files as an input. So I was wondering if there are any tools out there that can convert my .obj file to elf or dwarf file?

I did some digging on the Keil website ([here](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/93.htm)) and according to it, the obj file that is generated is OMF-51 (not sure why 51 is mentioned in the format name).

With this information I tried using a tool that I found on Github called objconv ([here](https://github.com/gitGNU/objconv)) which claimed to be able to convert OMF to ELF but I ran into an error when I tried it.

I hope someone can suggest some simpler ways to solve my problem or any other tool that is out there.

Edit : I tried using objcopy and looks like OMF-51 is not a supported format. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What did your research for another compiler (generating ELF output) reveal? -- What errors did the converter output? -- Which other tool would you like to use for debugging? Did you try to use `objcopy` (from the "binutils" of GCC) to generate ELF object files? -- OMF-51 is a special flavor of OMF for 8051.

Comment: * Changing my compiler is my last resort and I haven't looked much into this. I will consider this when nothing else works.
* I ran the following command : objconv -felf32 -nu main.obj genelf.o and I get the following error : Error 2018: Unknown type 0xFF026F70 for file: main.obj (I uncommented a line in the source code to get the error code)
* Thanks for referring to this tool. I will look into it now.

Comment: FYI *objconv* and *objcopy* are two different tools. *objcopy* is part of GNU binutils, and it doesn't support OMF.

Comment: It's unlikely that the ELF or DWARF formats will be useful for developing for the 8051, because the 8051 is an 8-bit microcontroller, and ELF supports 32-bit and 64-bit. It's possible, but very unlikely. Do you have an example ELF file which your *another tool* supports? Can you link (attach) it to the question?